# Server randomly disconnects all SSH session and stops accepting them for a short period

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm using a remote Ubuntu server running 18.04. SSH works fine most of the time however I'll randomly get disconnected from the server with this error:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

Unlike most of the questions already asked, this happens not only if the session is idle but most of the time whenever executing a command or printing out large text files.

Once I get disconnected, the server refuses to connect for some time after that but then always always me connect moments later.

```
ssh: connect to host internal.a1motion.com port 22: Connection refused
```

No where in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/auth.log` shares any additional information about why I was disconnected.

Comment: Run ssh connection in debug mode, maybe you'll get additional info. ssh -vvvv

Comment: It's a flaky network.

Answer (score 1):

If you using Putty as ssh client application do the below steps to increase keep-alive time interval. It may rectify your time out error.

Click on Connection
Type 120 into "Seconds between keepalives"

Moreover, run ssh connection in debug mode, maybe you'll get additional info. Also, do the following changes at the server end.

/etc/ssh/ssh_config
ServerAliveInterval 60
ServerAliveCountMax 120

Additionally, add a rule in ssh service and in the firewall that to accept SSH request from known IP address of your networks.